# Copy files from multiple folders to another multiple folders Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a huge list of files from different folder and i need to copy them to another folder.

I have already created those folders which I will copy.

I have tried the code:

```
for file in $(cat /home/pdf/report/folder/files.txt | sed $'s/\r//'); do cp "$file" /home/pdf/report/folder/dest.txt; done
```

Is there any solutions in Linux?

Comment: Can you add a tree of the source and destination directories and files?

Comment: The structures of folders are really different.

Comment: Btw `/home/pdf/report/folder/dest.txt` doesn't look like a directory, and if it is indeed a file you'd be copying every file to the same destination, which would be the last file processed after execution.

Comment: Are you trying to copy all the files from the list to the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
while read file 
do
 cp "$file" /home/pdf/report/folder/ 
done < /home/pdf/report/folder/files.txt
```

The important point is you're copying into the folder without specifying the filename, just the folder, meaning the copy will have the same name as the original

Comment: Andrew, thank you for your answer. I am really sorry for late answer. I solved this problem with php) ` for($i=0; $i < 113970; $i++) {
  if (!copy($fileArr[$i], $targetArr[$i].$varArr[$i].".pdf")) {
      echo "Error...\n";
  }else {
   echo $fileArr[$i] . "copied\n";
  }
 }`